# 90s Sci-Fi movie where people were rabid; main characters looking for orange vaccine

Tags: story-identification

I saw this when I was young; I believe it's from the 1990s.

It seemed to be post apocalyptic; it definitely wasn't supposed to look modern. There was a virus or disease or something that turned the people rabid. One scene had a cave full of people who had barricaded themselves in to hide from the infected.

The main characters were going to find a guy who had the last of vaccine against it (he's the antagonist). The vaccine was in a powder form; I think it was orange. This is where the lead female makes her appearance.

I can't remember who any of the actors were.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! You may want to take the [tour] to understand the site better. I believe you've given us everything you could think of to identify this movie. That said, check out [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/80867), and [edit] in anything this may prompt you to remember.

Comment: One obvious question: how sure are you that the people were rabid? Was that actually stated? If so that might help narrow down the possibilities significantly; if not, this sounds a lot like a rather generic zombie movie.

Comment: *Tank 432* has orange powder, but it causes the derangement and it's too recent.

Comment: @MrLister sounds like a reasonable match, worth putting it as an answer.

Comment: @MrLister that would help future searchers. OP isn't the only one who benefits from story-id questions :-) plus, even if it's not the right one, maybe bumping it will draw the attention of someone able to provide a more definitive answer :)

Comment: @Jenayah OK, OK. I'm not sure why I didn't actually post this an an answer, t.b.h. Maybe I was waiting for a response from the OP if they remembered the year wrong.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're talking about [The Lost Future](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lost_Future), which has everything you ask for: post-apocalyptic, beasts whose bite turns people into mutants, people barricading themselves into a cave and a quest for the yellow powder which is in possession of the bad guy. [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1615091/mediaindex?ref_=tt_pv_mi_sm) has some photos which may jog your memory:

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

This one is from 2010 though, so it may not be the one. On the other hand, you're right that it wasn't supposed to look modern.

Comment: That first line of the question really hits me with the force of decades ..."I saw this when I was young; I believe it's from the 1990s"